# Unable to redirect to another page once email is sent using php

Tags: php

Hi i have written code for contact mail functionality everything is working fine but the problem is unable to redirect another page after mail is sent displaying message as message sent that's it.

```
             <?php
            require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
             // include("class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from within 
              class.phpmailer.php if not already loaded
               $name = $_POST['form_name'];
            $email = $_POST['form_email'];
            $phone = $_POST['form_phone'];
             $subject = $_POST['form_subject'];
              $messages = $_POST['form_message'];
                    $mail    = new PHPMailer();
                     $smtp_host         = "HOST";
                   $smtp_user       = "USER";
                    $smtp_password  = "SECRET";
                   $smtp_port       = "25";
               $mail_from       = $email;
              $mail_to      = "MAILTO";
              $mail_to_name     = "MAILNAME";

              $message = array();    
              $message[]= 'Name  :  '.trim($name).' ';
              $message[]='Phone  :  '.trim($phone).' ';   
              $message[]='Email  :  '.trim($email).' ';   
              $message[]='Message  :  '.trim($messages).' ';    
              $message = implode('<br/>', $message);    
               $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
               $mail->Host       = "{$smtp_host}";  // SMTP server
               $mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;                  // enables SMTP debug 
               information (for testing)
                                    // 1 = errors and messages
                                    // 2 = messages only
                $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;               // enable SMTP authentication
                $mail->Host       = "{$smtp_host}";     // sets the SMTP server
                $mail->Port       = $smtp_port;         // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
             $mail->Username   = "{$smtp_user}";    // SMTP account username
             $mail->Password   = "{$smtp_password}"; // SMTP account password
             $mail->SetFrom("{$mail_from}", "{$mail_from_name}");
             $mail->Subject    = "$subject";
             $mail->MsgHTML($message);

            $address = "{$mail_to}";
            $mail->AddAddress($address, "{$mail_to_name}" );
            if(!$mail->Send()) {
               echo  "Error while sending email"; 
               } else {
                 echo "message sent";
            header("Location:contact.html");
             }
```

I am getting this error :

```
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:220-cp.rdsindia.in ESMTP Exim 4.91 #1 Tue, 19 Mar 2019 18:45:10 +0530 220-We do not authorize the use of this system to transport unsolicited, 220 and/or bulk e-mail.
SMTP -> FROM SERVER: 250-cp.rdsindia.in Hello rdaconsulting.in [64.62.254.150] 250-SIZE 52428800 250-8BITMIME 250-PIPELINING 250-AUTH PLAIN LOGIN 250-STARTTLS 250 HELP
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 OK
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 Accepted
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:354 Enter message, ending with "." on a line by itself
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:250 OK id=1h6EaE-0005nk-5J
SMTP -> FROM SERVER:221 cp.rdsindia.in closing connection
```

Comment: You must not create any output before sending headers, but with the `echo "message sent";` you are doing that.

Comment: "Unable to" means what? If you get a specific error or unexpected behaviour please tell us what is happening. I suspect 04FS is correct, and you should get an error or warning about it (maybe on screen or in logs, depending on your configuration) but it's better if you make the situation fully clear to begin with.

Comment: @ADyson not getting any errors its not redirecting to header location which i have given

Comment: @04FS i have removed  printing option as well but still it is not redirecting

Comment: Then please make sure first of all, that you have proper PHP error reporting enable, so that PHP can tell if it is has issues sending the header at that point.

Comment: @04FS i am getting this message once mail is sent

Comment: That doesn’t look like actual errors, that is just debug output you get due to `$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;` … Do you have proper _PHP_ error reporting enabled, yes or no?

Comment: @i have solved workign for redirection as well sorry for posting here

Comment: @04FS i have solved that already with redirectiona s well

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
   require_once('class.phpmailer.php');
   // include("class.smtp.php"); // optional, gets called from within class.phpmailer.php if not already loaded
   $name = $_POST['form_name'];
  $email = $_POST['form_email'];
   $phone = $_POST['form_phone'];
  $subject = $_POST['form_subject'];
  $messages = $_POST['form_message'];

    $mail    = new PHPMailer();
    $smtp_host      = "domain.in";
    $smtp_user      = "info@gmail.in";
    $smtp_password  = "12%^&*";
     $smtp_port         = "25";
    $mail_from      = $email;
   $mail_from_name = $name ;
   $mail_to         = "mail@gmail.in";
   $mail_to_name    = "Ronsulting";

     $message = array();    
    $message[]= 'Name  :  '.trim($name).' ';
    $message[]='Phone  :  '.trim($phone).' ';   
     $message[]='Email  :  '.trim($email).' ';   
     $message[]='Message  :  '.trim($messages).' '; 

     $message = implode('<br/>', $message); 

           $mail->IsSMTP(); // telling the class to use SMTP
           $mail->Host       = "{$smtp_host}";  // SMTP server
           $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;               // enable SMTP authentication
           $mail->Host       = "{$smtp_host}";  // sets the SMTP server
            $mail->Port       = $smtp_port;         // set the SMTP port for the GMAIL server
           $mail->Username   = "{$smtp_user}";  // SMTP account username
            $mail->Password   = "{$smtp_password}"; // SMTP account password

            $mail->SetFrom("{$mail_from}", "{$mail_from_name}");
             $mail->Subject    = "$subject";
             $mail->MsgHTML($message);

             $address = "{$mail_to}";
             $mail->AddAddress($address, "{$mail_to_name}" );
               if(!$mail->Send()) {
              echo  "Error while sending email"; 
               } else {
                header('Location:contact.html');
                    }
                  echo "<script type='text/javascript'>window.location.href='http://domain.in/contact.html'</scrip 
  t>";
```